# Changing Recyclerview background color makes toolbar disappear - Why so

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview

I am trying to change my recyclerview background colour and it is working fine in android oreo and android Q , i tried to test my app in kitkat and jellybean but something wierd is happening . When i use this line `android:background="@color/backgroundColorRecyclerView"` my title bar is gone and some thing like this happens[image: Title bar gone]

and when i remove this line every thing works fine like this [image]

I have been trying to figure out for hours nothing works .

Here is my app_bar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my content_main .xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColorRecyclerView"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_ad_main">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is toolbar code in xml ?

Comment: @HemantParmar I think he is using the system default Toolbar and not a custom one.

Comment: yes i am using default toolbar

Comment: you have create toolbar in xml after that put recyleview below toolbar. in your code your recyleview height is match parent that's why toolbar is overriding.

Comment: @John, `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` add this line to recyleview and check.

Comment: i have updated my code please take a look , evrything works fine in android 8 but the toolbar doesn't show in kitkat or jelly bean

Comment: @VedprakashWagh system default toolbar won't work on all devices.

Comment: tried your solution doesn't work

Comment: @HemantParmar then how should i make my toolbar

Comment: I guess `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` must be added into you `content_main`.

Comment: worked like charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what finally worked

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColorRecyclerView"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_ad_main">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```